# How to convert NSTextView RTFD data to plain text in cocoa

Tags: nstextview, nsattributedstring, string-conversion

I have one NSTextView containing formatted text and embedded images like following.

[image: NSTextView with formatted text and embedded image]

I want convert above into plain text like following:

```
Hi this is test data (...picture...)This is colored text.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying few hours i came up with the following solution for my own requirement.Please let me know if we can have better way to do that.

I have created NSString category with following code:

```
+ (NSString *)plainTextFromRTFD:(NSTextStorage *)aTextStorage 
           attachmentString:(NSString *)aString {

NSString *returnString = @"";

//Default value of aString, If nil
if (aString == nil) {
    aString = @"(...Attachment...)";
}

if (aTextStorage && aString) {

    //Initialize NSMutableString object to hold plain text
    NSMutableString *plainText = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    //Loop through all the attributes one-by-one to identify the NSAttachment
    for(int i =0;i<[aTextStorage length];i++) {

        NSDictionary *attr= [aTextStorage attributesAtIndex:i effectiveRange:NULL];

        //Check whether attribute contains NSAttachment or not
        if ([attr objectForKey:@"NSAttachment"] != nil) {
            //Replace NSTextAttachment with attachmentString value
            [plainText appendFormat:@"%@",aString];
        } else {
            //Add character to plain text
            [plainText appendFormat:@"%@",[[[aTextStorage characters] objectAtIndex:i] string]];    
        }
    }

    //copy NSString from NSMutableString
    returnString = [plainText copy];

    //release NSMutableString
    [plainText release];
}

return [returnString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];}
```

And, i am using it like following:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSString plainTextFromRTFD:[contentView textStorage] attachmentString:nil]);
```

Where contentView is NSTextView.

Comment: The above code will produce "Hi this is test data (...Attachment...)This is colored text." plain text.